# Why does only one of my controls get added to this form?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I'm working on a debugging application and I'm building a form ( based on a very small extension of the System.Windows.Form ) that is intended to take in a Constructor and create a new Parameter control for each Parameter in the Constructor.

My issue at the moment is that for some reason, my ParameterControls are being added to the form, but only the first one added is visible at the end of the operation.

The code in question and the supporting method; are as follows:

```
class ConstructorDialog : Namespace.Forms.Form
{
    protected void InitializeInterface()
    {
        if (this.TargetType == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot GenerateFields for ConstructorDialog. ConstructorDialog TargetType is null.");
        }
        else if (this.TargetConstructor == null)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            foreach( ParameterInfo Parameter in this.TargetConstructor.GetParameters())
            {
                try
                {
                    ParameterControl NewParameterControl = new ParameterControl(Parameter);
                    NewParameterControl.Location = new Point(0, 30 + (30 * Parameter.Position));
                    this.AddControl(NewParameterControl);
                    continue;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                }
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}

class Namespace.Forms.Form : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    public Control AddControl(Control Control)
    {
        if (Control == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Form cannot AddControl. Control is null.");
        else
        {
            this.Controls.Add(Control);
            return Control;
        }
    }
}


class Namespace.Debugging.ParameterControl : Namespace.Forms.UserControl
{
    protected void InitializeInterface()
    {
        if (this.TargetParameter == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot InitializeInterface for ConstructorParameterControl. ConstructorParameterControl TargetParameter is null.");
        }
        else
        {
            this.Controls.Clear();

            this.AddLabel(this.TargetParameter.Name + "_Label", this.TargetParameter.Name, new Point(25,0));

            return;
        }
    }
}

class Namespace.Forms.UserControl : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
{
    public Label AddLabel(String LabelName, String LabelText, Point Location)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(LabelName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(LabelText))
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        else
        {
            Label NewLabel = new Label();

            NewLabel.Name = LabelName;
            NewLabel.Text = LabelText;
            NewLabel.Location = Location;

            return this.AddLabel(NewLabel);
        }
    }

    public Label AddLabel(Label Label)
    {
        if (Label == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        else
        {
            this.Controls.Add(Label);
            return Label;
        }
    }
}
```

My Form extension is still in its infancy, so it's quite likely that I overlooked something ( especially since my forms knowledge is only apprentice-worthy ), but this operation seems simple enough and in my assessment ought to work.

Some debugging information:

```
The controls are being added to the base 'Controls' collection.
The positions of the controls are being set to what they ought to, so it is not a matter of them overlapping.
No exceptions are encountered during execution.
```

Comment: Do controls have their Width and Height set to positive values? Are their Visible properties true?

Comment: I haven't manually changed the values of any of these fields in the subsequent methods. All that happens in the construction of these controls is a new label is created and the text is set... I suppose I could force values on those fields though...

Comment: I ran into this problem after not getting very far in, as you may be able to assess.

Comment: Not your issue, but why do you have a continue with nothing after it?

Comment: Habitual... Makes easier reading for me for some reason - reassures me that that's what's gonna happen there. One of the guys who had a part in my learning used to yell at me too; but it ain't goin' away any time soon lol. I tend to get carried away with returns too ( I.E. the one in the same method is entirely unnecessary ). *shrug*

Comment: I suppose the question could be begged - Why does anyone write code on more than one line? Why do some people put spaces inside of there parentheses and others don't? All preference and readability I suppose.

Comment: Tough crowd though...

Comment: Try assigning the `Location` property *After* you've added the control to the form...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @sysexpand, I manually set the height and width of the ParameterControl objects, as well as setting the 'Visible' property to true and seem to have resolved the issue.

My assessment of this is that by setting these variables before the ParameterControl is a member of its parent, these variables are being overwritten when the control is added to its parent.

Comment: You could now check your own answer :). It's permitted. You've actually done a good thing telling the community what difficulties you've encountered and then showing a solution to the problem. You could also mention in a line that @sysexpand said you should try to look at these 3 properties an hour ago, just for good fellowship :)

Comment: Could you also develop ideas on why the 1st control would always show up, and the trailing N-1 controls would only show up if you would set their 3 properties (Width, Height and Visible) to appropriate values ? Just wondering and other readers will also be wondering. If it's clear to you, please write a few thoughts. If it's not clear already, then I'm sure you're dying to find out why yourself...

Comment: I'll gladly follow up on these comments very shortly; I'm at work and not in a good position to be sharing with the community for the next hour or so :P